# Calculate a Mathematic formula for each element of array field - Mongodb Aggregation Framework

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a array field containing some elements values as following :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a535c48a4d86ed94a7e8618"),
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a"  
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "b   
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "a" 
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"  
        },
        {
            "value" : "a"  
        },
        {
            "value" : "a" 
        }
    ]
}



/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a535c48a4d86ed94a7e8619"),
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a" 
        }, 
        {
            "value" : c"  
        }, 
        { 
            "value" : "c" 
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to make a an aggregation to calculate some weight for each element of the myArrayField :

```
db.col.aggregate([{'$addFields':{
'myArray':{  
      '$concatArrays':[      
          {'$map':{
              'input':'$myArray',
              'as':'val',
              'in':{'value':'$$val.value','weight': X }
            }}
        ]} 
   ,
  'size':{'$size':'$myArray'}  
  }
},
{'$sort':{'size':-1}}
])
```

With this aggregation, I get as a new field weight with a weight value X of each element. My problem is the calculation of this X.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a535c48a4d86ed94a7e8618"),
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a",
            "weight" : Xa 
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "b,
            "weight" : Xb   
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "a",
            "weight" : Xa  
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c" ,
            "weight" : Xc  
        },
        {
            "value" : "a",
            "weight" : Xa   
        },
        {
            "value" : "a" ,
            "weight" : Xa 
        }
    ],
  "size": 6
}



/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a535c48a4d86ed94a7e8619"),
    "myArray" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a" ,
            "weight" : Xa 
        }, 
        {
            "value" : c" ,
            "weight" : Xc 
        }, 
        { 
            "value" : "c" ,
            "weight" : Xc 
        }
    ],
  "size": 3

}
```

This famous weight X is a mathematic formula that need a accumulator sum as you will find this image bellow.

[image: The Formula of the weight X]

I need someone to help me to perform this formula to calculcate this variable.

Exemple for the first item `(a)` of `myArray` of the first document :
`Xa = 1/(2^0*(1+1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16+1/32))` because 0 is the position of the element -1 and we have as a size 6 elements.

Comment: @Veeram can you help me in this please, I think you understand more my logic

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
    "myArray":{
      "$map":{
        "input":{"$range":[0,{"$size":"$myArray"}]},
        "in":{
          "$let":{
            "vars":{"e":{"$arrayElemAt":["$myArray","$$this"]}},
            "in":{
              "value":"$$e.value",
              "weight":{
                "$divide":[
                  1,
                  {"$multiply":[
                    {"$pow":[2,"$$this"]},
                    {"$sum":{
                      "$map":{
                        "input":{"$range":[0,{"$size":"$myArray"}]},
                        "in":{"$divide":[1,{"$pow":[2,"$$this"]}]}
                      }
                    }}
                  ]}
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you @Veeram for your help, it's very kind from you.. I don't know why I get an empty array without fields after aggregation

Comment: You are very welcome. It outputs an array with values when run with data from post. Are you using the same data for your test ? If no, please update the post with the data you are testing with and I can check.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's the same, it's about an array as a field and some unused others metrics. but we will work just with the array. :(

Comment: You just have to change `$project` to `$addFields` to retain other fields. Is that what you are asking ? do your array has the new weight field with calculated values ?

Comment: Yes I did it, but I get an empty array without value and weight field

Comment: I think I get the solution, I get an emty array when I have a Array with one element it's normal we have to add the case of size=1

Comment: yeah try now. I've fixed the range. It was not iterating all the elements earlier.

Comment: I think I don't have to reach size(myArray) in the range it's from 0 to size-1 .. so for the case of 1 element the range will be `"$range":[0]` with one element 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162999/discussion-between-dr-mza-and-veeram).